# How to add a dot to particular lines in LaTeX-document?

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a LaTeX-document where I have lines of the form

```
\section*{3.1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{3.1}
```

or in general

```
\section*{x.y}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{x.y}
```

for x between 1 and 31 and y between 1 and 12 inclusively, (dates). I would like to change those lines to the form

```
\section*{x.y.}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{x.y.}
```

Is there some easy script to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sed, match the before and after parts of the line and put a `.` in the middle. The command `s/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/` performs a regular expression replacement. `\(…\)` delimits a group; `\1` and `\2` in the replacement text refer to these groups.

```
sed <original.tex >replaced.tex \
    -e 's/^\(\\section\\*{[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)\(}\)$/\1.\2/' \
    -e 's/^\(\\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)\(}\)$/\1.\2/'
```

Another way to use sed is to replace the last `}` by `.}` if the line matches the desired pattern:

```
sed <original.tex >replaced.tex \
    -e '/^\\section\\*{[0-9]*\.[0-9]*}\)$/ s/}$/.&/' \
    -e '/^\\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{[0-9]*\.[0-9]*}/ s/}$/.&/'
```

You can also use `\|` to combine two patterns but in this case I think it makes the code shorter but less clear.

If you want to replace the file in place, under Linux, you can use

```
sed -i -e … somefile.tex
```